# Цитату можно оформить без кавычек?

Tags: цитата

1. Цитаты заключаются в кавычки. Если цитата оформляется как прямая речь, т.е. сопровождается словами автора, приводящего ее, то применяются соответствующие правила пунктуации (см. §119–122).
   Белинский писал: «Создает человека природа, но развивает и образует его общество».

Следует ли из этого, что если цитата сопровождается словами автора, то можно ли применять не кавычки, а тире:

Белинский писал:

-- Создает человека природа, но развивает и образует его общество.

-- Создает человека природа, но развивает и образует его общество, -- цитирует издание Белинского.

Comment: можно ли писать "цитирует издание такого-то", если этот кто-то дал интервью этому же изданию? Или же правильно после цитаты написать _приводит издание слова такого-то_? Ведь _Цитата, выдержка – это текст из какого-либо произведения, дословно воспроизводимый автором в издании._

Comment: doom,не совсем понятно, что именно Вас интересует.  Объясните, пожалуйста, яснее.

Answer (score 4):

Кавычки может заменить шрифтовое выделение, или кегль, или гарнитура, или заключение в рамочку... Это не относится к письму "от руки".

Но тире в этом случае отдыхает, оно для передачи прямой речи.

Белинский писал:

***СОЗДАЁТ ЧЕЛОВЕКА ПРИРОДА, НО РАЗВИВАЕТ И ОБРАЗУЕТ ЕГО ОБШЕСТВО.***

Можно, не меняя шрифт, обыграть цитату цветом, и тоже избавимся от кавычек.

В общем, это возможности набора - всё типографское мне хорошо знакомо, компьютерное - нет.

---

А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова. Справочник издателя и автора. Редакционно-издательское оформление издания:

> **Выделение цитат (для многострочных цитат)**
>
> а) втяжка, если цитата не превышает страницы; б) втяжка с вертикальной
>   линейкой в ней, если цитата может быть не видна читателю (или шрифт
>   меньшего кегля или другой гарнитуры).
>
> **Цитаты, не заключаемые в кавычки**
>
> 1. Выделенные шрифтовым или нешрифтовым способом (шрифтом другого кегля, рисунка, начертания; втяжкой; напечатанные иной, чем основной
>      текст, краской) или если по контексту читателю ясно, что перед ним
>      цитата. Напр.: Пушкин писал жене: *Что-то дети мои и книги мои?*

---

[**8.2.2. Цитаты, не заключаемые в кавычки**](http://orfogrammka.ru/ogl03/70091470.html)

Answer (score 1):

Текст цитаты всегда выделяется в кавычки, даже когда начинается с абзаца.

Если цитата состоит из нескольких абзацев, то кавычки ставят только в начале и в конце всего текста:

В статье «Из истории русской литературы» М. Горький писал:

> «Чем же сильна литература?
>
> Насыщая идеи плотью и кровью, она даёт им большую наглядность, большую убедительность, чем философия или наука».

Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь.Д.Э.